# How to redirect QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo to local files?

Tags: c++, qt, http-redirect, http-protocols, qwebengineview

I have a simple Qt application that loads a page in a `QWebEngineView`. I would like to redirect all http requests with the word "static" in the url to local files. Using `WebUrlRequestInterceptor` I reimplemented the `interceptRequest` method. Here is the code:

```
class MyWebUrlRequestInterceptor : public QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
{
public:
    void interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo &info) {
        if (info.requestUrl().toString().contains("static")) {
            QString newUrl = QDir::currentPath() + info.requestUrl().toString().mid(21, info.requestUrl().toString().length());
            qDebug() << "new url = " << newUrl;
            info.redirect(QUrl::fromLocalFile(newUrl));
        }
    }
};
```

In main function I did

```
MyWebUrlRequestInterceptor *wuri = new MyWebUrlRequestInterceptor();
QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->setRequestInterceptor(wuri);
```

And the `interceptRequest` seems to work fine, but I get a message.

> Not allowed to load local resource

I searched online and I many people are saying that I should add the `--disable-web-security` flag. So i did in my `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --disable-web-security
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different solutions? Could I make custom protocols to serve local files and redirect to them in Qt as a workaround?

I'm using Qt 5.9.1 and QtCreator 4.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

I would block the request using *QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo::block* and load the local file in the *QWebEngineView* (even read the local file on the fly and pass its content to the view through *QWebEngineView::setHtml*).

Or listen locally for incoming http requests, using local dir as web root, and eventually redirect to localhost when needed, which implies using an external web server or building a minimal one, maybe integrated in your app. If you go for integrating it, I would consider this one: https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose.

Comment: Thanks @p-a-o-l-o! I'm not sure I understand. If the page is asking for an image, how can I load it via `setHtml`?

Comment: If the file content is not html, you'd be better using a local web server, as suggested. Before trying to embed one, you can test this solution using an external one, maybe express, if you're into nodejs (https://expressjs.com)